# How to access contents of a SimpleArrayField in Python Django

Tags: python, arrays, django, list, forms

I am currently working with a form class in Django. I need to be able to access data contained in a SimpleArrayField.

```
class SignUps(forms.Form)
 people = SimpleArrayField(forms.EmailField(), label="name")
```

Let's say a user fills out the form with the names `"John Smith," "Jane Smith", "Mike Smith"`.

I need to be able to access the names. I've tried various methods such as

```
print(people["name"])
```

or

```
print(people[0])
```

But I keep getting the error

```
TypeError: 'SimpleArrayField' object is not subscriptable.
```

I've tried to figure out to access fields from a SimpleArrayObject, but I don't see any examples in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/forms/). How would I go about getting the names from the `people` object? Is that even possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SimpleArrayField is intended to allow you to encode a list of values together as a single string (e.g. the value `"1,2,3,4"` could represent the array of integers `[1,2,3,4]`). You have specified that the values in the array are `forms.EmailField()`, so it's expecting that the value will be something like `"foo@bar.com,myemail@gmail.com"`. When the form is submitted, you'll have an array of email strings under the `"name"` key in the  `form.cleaned_data`

Comment: Thank you, accessing the cleaned_data field was helpful to me and I was able to get the data I needed!